# NextAuth EmailProvider not creating an account (only user)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

This may be on purpose but when a user authenticates via gitHub ext nextAuth generate a user, then also an account to go with the user holing name / image source token ext.  I am using the account data to interact with my site in dev, and I want to mainly use EmailProvider as I can link the acounts from my current vbulletin site on the email key, ie when they log in with EmailProvider i can check an import table and set the username to the old username.  I see that for some reason nextAuth does not generate an account though whenusing EmailProvider only a user.

Would love to hear if this is normal and I need to generate an account on my own or if this is not working as intended.

Currently working with prisma / typescript /next.js / nextAuth